# How to get foreign key attribute (and many to many attribute) of a model instance in Django in asynchronous queries?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await

In asynchronous queries, I want to get foreign key and many to many attributes of a model instance.
In a simple example, I want to print `university` and `courses` for all instances of the model `Student`.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    university = models.ForeignKey(to=University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(to=Course)
```

when I use this code (in django 4.1):

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    async for student in Student.objects.all():
        
        print(student.name)

        print(student.university.name)

        for course in student.courses.all():
            print(course.name)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just a suggestion.  Try `student = await student` or `student = await student.university.afirst()` before printing `student.university` etc...  I'm new to Djang async, but from my experience with JavaScript, this might be the issue.

Comment: @raphael thank you for your comment. but none of them worked. it is possible to print `student.name`, but get the error for `student.university` which is a foreign key.

Comment: Can you try removing the `to=` part in your university and courses fields of your student model. I mean change it to `university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.  Doubt it’s the problem, but I’ve never seen it defined this way. I have seen `to_field=`, but I don’t think you need that here.

Comment: @raphael No. `to=` is not the problem. I always use this format. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting foreign key and many to many attributes (for **django 4.1** or higher) in async queries:

#### Foreign key attribute:

There are two options for getting foreign key attribute:

1-

```
async for student in Student.objects.all():
    university = await University.objects.aget(id=student.university_id)
    print(university.name)
```

2-

```
async for student in Student.objects.select_related("university").all():
    print(student.university.name)
```

#### Many to Many attribute:

```
async for student in Student.objects.all():
    async for course in student.courses.all():
            print(course.name)
```